Blender video output has bad quality

i am rendering a simple video but it is pixelated i tried doing it frame by frame and the .png frames look amazing but then when i put them in sequence the quality goes low again.


Well, you've cut out the interesting parts in your screenshot: all the settings below Encoding.

Change the Output → Encoding → Video → Output Quality to Perceptually Lossless:


Hmmm this doesn't actually explain why his got pixelated. Setting it to lossless will bloat the video. There's something wrong with his setup. I always have mine at Medium quality and the quality is good enough.

@HarryMcKenzie true, I didn't explicitly explain where the artifacts come from, but I though it's obvious and implied by the setting change those are compression artifacts. As for the bloat: there's 3 elements here: compression speed, output quality and output size, can't improve on all 3.

I find it weird though I've never seen such extreme artifacts in my renders so I thought that maybe there was something wrong with the compression.
